# Changing the "Hover Area" Shape of a Button

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, hover

[image: A button which grow bigger when mouse pointer enter the hover area.]

```
  <Button x:Name="ListItem_Button_Play" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Style="{StaticResource PlayButtonStyle}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
          <Image Source="Resources/ListItem_Button_Play.png"/>
  </Button>
```

I have a `Button` in my `DataTemplate`. I applied a `Style` to it to remove the default hover effect. Also, to make it grow bigger when mouse pointer enter the hover area.

```
    <Style x:Key="PlayButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                        Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=border}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        CornerRadius="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=border}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="93"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="93"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="93" To="103" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="93" To="103" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="103" To="93" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="103" To="93" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I successfully changed the `Border` shape of the `Button` to follow the `Image` (ellipse). But not the hover area.

After some experiments, i can conclude that although the shape of the `Border` has changed, the shape of hover area are still the same. The red area above is the hover area.

Is there a way to change the Hover Area shape just like the "Play" `Image` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid things like the Height/Width bindings you have whose path is itself. RelativeSource if you need, but in this case none of that should be necessary. Besides, you already have two `Setter`'s halfway down with your `Height` and `Width` hard set already...

I made a few minor tweaks but this should sort you out and tests fine on my end.

```
<Style x:Key="PlayButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="93"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="93"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="border"
                                    CornerRadius="50"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>                    
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation From="93" To="103" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation From="93" To="103" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation From="103" To="93" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation From="103" To="93" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```